# Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose() with Firebase Realtime Database chat feature

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am receiving this error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _EventChatScreenState#7c8b5(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
#0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/wid<…>
```

However, the only place I am calling `setState` is in the `initState`:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    dbRef = dbInstance.ref("/events/");
    var query = dbRef!.child(widget.event.event.eventId);
    FirebaseList(
      query: query,
      onChildAdded: (index, snapshot) {
        Map<dynamic, dynamic> childMap = snapshot.value as dynamic;
        ChatMessage newChatMessage = ChatMessage(
          chatMessageId: snapshot.key.toString(),
          userId: childMap["userId"],
          displayName: childMap["displayName"],
          message: childMap["message"],
          datetime: childMap["datetime"],
        );

        setState(() {
          chatMessages.add(newChatMessage);
        });
      },
    );
    _messageFieldController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _messageFieldController.dispose();
  }
```

I'm not really sure why this is happening, but I included the `dispose` method since it the error references it.

Worth noting that I am doing this to make the screen scroll to the bottom of the chat messages which are display using a `ListView.builder`

```
void scrollToBottom() {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = ref.watch(userProvider);
    if (chatMessages.isNotEmpty) {
      scrollToBottom();
    }
```

If I remove the above code the issue seems to go away

Comment: Your firebase list code should be in the build method, not in initState.

Comment: @GrahamD Why is that? How does `FireaseList` handle this that that's possible since in another post where I was using a StreamBuilder you said to create the stream in the `initState` method?

Comment: Also it seems as though I have resolved the issue by moving `var query` to the root level of the state class and changing how the variable is created to `Query? dbQuery;` but I'm not sure why that's fixed it...

Comment: build can be called again in many situations. Such as state change or parent rebuild.

While initState is called only one time.
build should be used only for layout. While initState is usually used for variable initialization. Courtesy of Remi R. See https://flutterbyexample.com/lesson/stateful-widget-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

**instead of this**

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _messageFieldController.dispose();
  }
```

**try this**

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _messageFieldController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```